# Find an injective group homomorphism $\varphi: D_4 → Sym_4$ with $D_4$ being the dihedral group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, abelian-groups, symmetry

Let $D_4$ be the dihedral group and $\circ$ be the composition of transformations.

Exercise:

- Find an injective group homomorphism $\varphi: D_4 → Sym_4$ and determine if $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Already done:

1. Show that $(D_4,\circ)$ is a group.
2. Determine $|D_4|$.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you label the vertices of the square then you have a set with four elements. Each transformation of the square then gives rise to a permutation of these elements.

Comment: How exactly we define $\varphi$ depends on how your textbook defines $D_4$.  What is your definition of $D_4$?

Comment: @user722227 Thanks, I will try to think about it that way.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $D_4$ isn't really strictly defined, all we have is a picture of a square with arrows indicating the legal move.

Comment: How did you show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism, without first showing that $D_4$ is a group? That's part of the definition of group homomorphism!

Comment: Anyway, if you have found an injective map from $D_4$ to $S_4$, then to find the number of elements of $D_4$ all you have to do is count the number of elements in the image of your injective map.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I already have shown that $D_4$ is a group, as stated, but haven't found such a $\varphi$ and determined if this $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: OK, I interpreted "already done" as referring upward, not downward. Sorry.

Comment: So, label the vertices of the square with the numbers $1,2,3,4$ and then corresponding to each element of $D_4$ you get a map from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to itself, that is, a member of $S_4$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Got it now. I can't accept your answer as it's a comment, but still: thanks a lot. Just to check: It's not an isomorphism, as $|D_4| = 8 \ne 24 = |Sym_4|$, right?

Comment: It's an answer, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the vertices of the square with the numbers $1,2,3,4$, and then corresponding to each element of $D_4$ you get a map from $\{\,1,2,3,4\,\}$ to itself, that is, a member of $S_4$. This gives you your injection (not an isomorphism, as $D_4$ has eight elements; $S_4$, $24$).